# Bind data to dynamically generated textbox in View using jquery - MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

In SQL DB i have table with ProjectID,taskID,workedHours,Date fields and want to bind this workedHrs to particular ProjectName,TaskName in a view.
I have a table in View as following :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr style="background-color:#ded9d9;color:#000">
                    <td colspan="9" id="Pn">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project_Name)
                        @Html.Hidden("TProjectId", item.Project_Id)
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:6%; width:22%;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.Task_Name)
                        @Html.Hidden("TTaskId", item.Task_Id)
                    </td>
                    <td style=" width:7%;">                        
                        <input id="Day1" name="Day1" type="text" value="" style="width:70%;" disabled="disabled" />
                    </td>
        </tr>
        }
```

I generate Day1 textbox dynamically for each Project,Task items in model. Here I want to bind data to this dynamically generated textboxes. I want to fetch each row ProjectId/ProjectName,TaskID /TaskName to match with available values and then bind data to textboxes based on ProjectId.
How can i achieve this using Jquery ....

Can anyone help me to do this....
Thanks in advance...

I attached an sample image of view[image: bind data to Worked Hrs textbox]

I get data from handler and bring to view as following :

```
 $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "/Infrastructure/Handler/GetTimsheetData.ashx",
               data: "",
               success: function (response) {
                   var temp; var PId; var TId;
                   temp = JSON.stringify(response);
                   var data = JSON.stringify(response);                   
                   console.log('data: ' + data);
                   $("#TestTimesheetData").append(data);
        }
    });
```

In side form, I add the table and bind the response to this table

```
 <table id="TestTimesheetData"></table>
```

I planned to get ProjectId,TaskID,workedHrs from this table and then bind this workedHrs to appropriate textbox matching ProjeID,TaskID in this table

Initially, I bind data to model from controller using view bag as following :

```
 objParent = new TestDAO().GetTimesheetPrjectDetails();
            ViewData["Project"] = objParent;
```

Comment: @Jan'splite'Kondelík I update my question. kindly review it

Comment: please post code on how you are generating your model and data for it.

Comment: @RobScott I post the code. kindly check it

Comment: is there JSON data in your response? it should be `var data = JSON.stringify(response.responseJSON);`. then you would iterate through your JSON and create a new `<tr>` and `<td>` w/ your properties in each appropriate control. Take a look at mustache.js to levy HTML templates